# unity add button using script programmatically with parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lambda

I have some buttons each represents some level and want to add the listener programmatically, but not quite familiar with the lambda function of C#(maybe some closure thing?), It's what I do now:

```
for(int i=0; i<levels.Count; i++){
   //omit the making a button snippet
   button.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
   {
         Debug.Log("load Scene");
         ApplicationModel.currentLevel = levels[i];

         SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
         //Application.LoadLevel("Game");
   });
}
```

But the line:

```
ApplicationModel.currentLevel = levels[i];
```

`levels` is a `List<Level>` and `ApplicationModel` is a class holding the info according to [this post](http://blog.christianhenschel.com/2013/05/16/how-to-pass-data-between-scenes-static-variables/#crayon-58eaddd07cae4846560309)
but it keeps give a ArgumentOutOfRangeException:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
Parameter name: index
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Level].get_Item (Int32 index) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:633)
GameLevelManger+<initScrollPanel>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () (at Assets/GameLevelManger.cs:72)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it keeps give a ArgumentOutOfRangeException:

the issue you're having is that by the time the variable `i` is used the for loop has completed and the value of `i` is `levels.Count`.

this is referred to as captured variables:

- The value of a variable is at the time it is used not at the time it is captured.
- The lifetime of a captured variable is extended till all the closures
  referencing the variable become eligible for garbage collection.

Rather what you can do is kind of create a decoy variable let's call it `capturedIndex` and let the lambda expression to capture the `capturedIndex` rather than the indexer of the for loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<levels.Count; i++){
   //omit the making a button snippet
   int capturedIndex = i;  // <-- let the lambda capture this rather than the indexer.
   button.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
   {
          Debug.Log("load Scene");
          ApplicationModel.currentLevel = levels[capturedIndex];
          SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
          //Application.LoadLevel("Game");
    });
}
```

further reading:

- [**Captured variable in a loop in C#**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp)
- [**Jeremy Bytes - Lambdas & LINQ in C# - Captured Variables &
  for Loops**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1onS_dCheY&index=4&list=PLdbkZkVDyKZU5ZXqp5YP1TS3irQKHZilU) (youtube video)
- [**Jon Skeet - The Beauty of Closures**](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, it helps. It will be even greater if you can add some more 
reference to read on :D

Comment: @armnotstrong if it has helped I'd appreciate it if you mark the answer as accepted and sure I will append some links for references.

Comment: thanks @Ousmane, I'll dig into it :D